# convert NSTaggedPointerString to NSString

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I had called an interface of Baidu to check id Number, however the value of Sex returned with `sex = M`, without "" around the `M` in JSON, when I use `NSString` in module to store it and then print the class name of this `sex` property, it printed as `NSTaggedPointerString`, I doubt how to convert it to a String to use it. Anyone have good ideas?

Comment: {
    errNum = 0;
    retData =     {
        address = "\U6e56\U5317\U7701\U7701\U76f4\U8f96\U53bf\U7ea7\U884c\U653f\U533a\U5212\U4ed9\U6843\U5e02";
        birthday = "1989-07-10";
        sex = M;
    };
    retMsg = success;
} This is the JSON that returns

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`NSTaggedPointerString` is already an `NSString`, it's just a subclass. You can use it anywhere you can use an `NSString`, without conversion.

Comment: Thanks, I just find it as I used the wrong arguments in swift, it should use %@ just as Obj-C but I used the %s instead. I fixed the error.

Comment: In my cace,when does not convert than makes warnning \n "Incompatible pointer types initializing ~~"

Comment: That's a different issue entirely. NSTaggedPointerString is about the dynamic type of the object. Your issue is about the type you have written in your source code.

Comment: `po [NSClassFromString(@"NSTaggedPointerString") superclass]` will prove your answer.

Comment: @Catfish_Man could you explain a little bit more about the the issue you described? Since I need to save the string into file but with `NSTaggedPointerString` it seemed not be saved correctly.

Comment: That sounds like something else. The issue I mentioned in the comments wouldn't apply to anything while the app is running, only when it's being compiled.

Comment: Try converting a number to a string and pass it on from one view controller to another, without doing something like stringWithString beforehand. You will see how "anywhere" is not actually _anywhere_.

Comment: I've done many things like that. It works fine. You have some other more subtle bug there that is being worked around.

Answer (score 11):

I have encountered places where `NSTaggedPointerString` cannot be used as a `NSString`, such as when creating an `NSDictionary`. In those cases use `stringWithString:`:

```
NSString* <# myNSString #> = [NSString stringWithString:<# myNSTaggegedString #>];
```

Comment: I found it easier to just say NSDictionary *aDict = @{[myvar valueForKey:@"item"] since the .property doesn't work well. KVO to the rescue

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue multiple times. It would seem that type inference for NSDictionary is not an exact science. What I do is specifically ask if the object responds to a particular method. For example if I am looping through parsing some JSON and I am attempting to access a value of type `NSString`:

```
NSString * string;
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"value"] respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
    string = [[dict objectForKey:@"value"] stringValue];
}
else {
   string = [NSString stringWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"value"]];
}
documentFile.documentRevision = string;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case son {"count":"123"} I got error.
Solved:

```
// Data was created, we leave it to you to display all of those tall tales!
// NSLog(@«data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

NSDictionary * json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ //Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
                  NSArray *dicArray = json[@"count"];
                   NSLog(@"=:%@", dicArray);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Swift 3 or 4**

```
String(stringInterpolationSegment: taggedPointerString)
```