# NSString category failing on NSTaggedPointerString

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I have a NSString category with a simple trim method in it. And it looks like my string is a NSTaggedPointerString and it won't evaluate properly.

Error:

```
[NSTaggedPointerString trim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What should I do to address this?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (StringHelper)

- (NSString *)trim;

@end


#import "NSString+Helper.h"

@implementation NSString (StringHelper)

-(NSString *)trim
{
    return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do other strings work?

Comment: Add your code to the question please.

Comment: This is pretty surprising; `NSTaggedPointerString` is a subclass of `NSString` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207376/convert-nstaggedpointerstring-to-nsstring). I would suspect that the category isn't being loaded at all. As @Willeke asked, does it work for non-taggedPointer strings? Perhaps you've missed an `-objc` linker flag and you're loading this from a library?

Comment: So it looks like I found a bit more. My Category is included in a static library, so that all of my project can use it. If I create a new category and add it to my project it works fine and I don't get the error. Ideas?

Comment: I figured it out, finally! For what ever reason I forgot to add "-ObjC" and "-all_load" to the other linker flags.